# DaRT 7.0 doesn't see my Windows installation

Tags: erd, dart

I created bootable CD for Microsoft DaRT 7.0.

And when I boot, it doesn't see my Windows 7 32bit Ultimate installation.

What can I do?

Comment: What's the problem that led you to try using DaRT in the first place?  Or put another way, *what makes you so sure the installation is even still there*?

Comment: There's no problem with my Windows installation. I just want to test DaRT but I could not because it doesn't see my Windows.

Comment: In that context, that's pretty weird.  I've never had a problem with it.

Comment: Is it the beta version of 7.0? Maybe some sata driver is missing?

Comment: Off topic, sort of, just found this, nice...http://www.petri.co.il/replace-default-windows-recovery-environment-in-dart.htm